# Reemplazar el texto de un campo tipo varchar en mi consulta - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, sql

Hice una consulta a la base de datos en donde tengo registrado los datos de tickets de soporte, estuve realizando pruebas por lo que algunos tickets no tienen tema de ayuda, cuando devuelven null, lo reemplazo por 'Tema no asignado' y todo normal, pero ahora quiero reemplazar un dato solo en la consulta, no en la tabla, por ejemplo si me devuelve el valor 'Jorge', quiero reemplazarlo por 'Marvin', pero solo en la consulta, no en la tabla, es esto posible?

Esta es mi consulta:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y la columna a la de cierra_ticket necesito cambiar el dato visible para el usuario.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida a SO. Ten la amabilidad de cambiar la imagen por el texto del código. En cuanto a la pregunta, sería una consulta parecida a esto: `SELECT CASE
        WHEN nombre = 'Jorge' THEN 'Marvin'
        ELSE nombre
    END AS nombre, otraColumna, masOtraColumna FROM tabla `  sería cuestión de incorporar algo así a la consulta que ya tienes usando los nombres de tabla/columna adecuados.

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración.

Comment: Gracias, es exactamente lo que necesitaba.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes resolverlo con algo como esto:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN nombre = 'Jorge' 
        THEN 'Marvin' 
        ELSE nombre 
    END AS nombre, 
    otraColumna, 
    masOtraColumna 
FROM tabla
```

Sería cuestión de incorporar algo así a la consulta que ya tienes usando los nombres de tabla/columna adecuados.

Para aprender más sobre `CASE ... WHEN` puedes ver [este tutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-case-function/) y también el [Manual de Referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case.html).